# DataGridView: how to bind specific data souce to a custom column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have DataGridView with several automatically generated columns. The data source is BindingList where cinema is a custom class with several string fields which a succesfully displayed in auto-generated columns. But this class also contains Area class field, which is also a custom class with 2 string fields. 
So finally, my question is how can I add 2 more columns binded specifically to Area object's string fields?

Comment: If all you want is two ADDITIONAL columns, they can be added manually to the DataGridView - Plenty of instructions on MSDN on how to do that.

Comment: But can I bind these columns to a different data source?

Comment: In order to answer that question, you will need to provide a lot more detail on what you are doing (see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and also describe what your desired outcome would be.

Comment: You could have a class that acts as a broker for the two different sources. You can add these data sources to the *broker*, which will generate an *even* number of rows from the different source using specific logic. Or it creates relations between two *tables*. It depends on what is relation between the two classes. You, probably, could simpy use a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, if this second class has the same values for all the main class members.